# Number of configurations in mlr3 hyperband tuning

Tags: mlr3

How can I control the number of configurations being evaluated during hyperband tuning in mlr3? I noticed that when I tune 6 parameters in xgboost(), the code evaluates about 9 configurations. When I tune the same number of parameters in catboost(), the code starts with evaluating 729 configurations. I am using eta = 3 in both cases.

Comment: If you want to specify the exact number of evaluations to do, a different approach (e.g. random search) would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of sampled configurations in hyperband is defined by the lower and upper bound of the budget hyperparameter and eta. You can get a preview of the schedule and number of configurations:

```r
mlr3hyperband::hyperband_schedule(r_min = 1, r_max = 81, eta = 3)

#>     bracket stage budget  n
#>  1:       4     0      1 81
#>  2:       4     1      3 27
#>  3:       4     2      9  9
#>  4:       4     3     27  3
#>  5:       4     4     81  1
#>  6:       3     0      3 34
#>  7:       3     1      9 11
#>  8:       3     2     27  3
#>  9:       3     3     81  1
#> 10:       2     0      9 15
#> 11:       2     1     27  5
#> 12:       2     2     81  1
#> 13:       1     0     27  8
#> 14:       1     1     81  2
#> 15:       0     0     81  5

mlr3hyperband::hyperband_n_configs(r_min = 1, r_max = 81, eta = 3)

#> 143
```

If you want to evaluate more configurations, increase the `repetition` parameter of hyperband. Hyperband will start again after evaluating the last bracket. Install the latest gh version for this `devtools::install_github("mlr-org/mlr3hyperband")`.